# WordPress wp_insert_post not inserting tags

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to insert a post with this code:

```
$my_post = array(
                'post_type'    => "essays",
                'post_title'    => 'TEST 3',
                //'post_content'  => $content,
                'post_status'   => 'draft',
                'post_author'   => 1,
                //'post_category' => $cat,
                'tags_input'    => 'TQM,tag',
        );

$post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
```

Everythings works ok except the tags, it does not insert any of them.
Any idea?

Comment: Does it return any errors? Not sure, but could it be there's a problem with non-existing tags?

Comment: No, I tried inserting exisiting tags and also doesn't work

Answer (score 8):

Use the `wp_set_object_terms()` function:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms

```
wp_set_object_terms($post_id , $arrayoftags, $name_of_tag_taxonomy, false);
```

Good luck

Answer (score 4):

Your post type is `essays`. Custom post types do not support tags by default. You'll have to add a `tags` taxonomy to them.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Comment: Not really sure about that... It isn't mentioned on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post anyway. I'm curious whether it will work or not for the TS

Comment: Nice one! I just overlooked it. That should do it.

Comment: I have the tags taxonomy registered. Also I can add tags manually through wp-admin, but in the code it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

tags and post categories ought to be entered as an array, even if it's only one. So `'tags_input'    => 'TQM,tag'`  should be `'tags_input'    => array('TQM,tag')`

Comment: Also tried it with an array... doesn't work.
Also this isn't an issue with new tags as using old ones also doesn't work

Comment: The solution of the array is correct but it should be `'tags_input' => array('TQM', 'tag')` (each tag is an array item).

Answer (score 0):

To insert the post with tags and categories do this

```
$pid=wp_insert_post($new_post);
wp_set_post_terms( $pid, $arrayoftags);
wp_set_post_categories( $pid, $arrayofcategories );
```

so $pid is the post id basically you first insert the post without tags or categories and the function returns the post's id which you can then use to insert the tags and categories each with their respective function, if you look at the source code of wp_insert_post you will notice that the function works in a different way for custom post types, I did not look more into it as I don't want to hack the code as there is a better solution by using the built in functions

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found this answer somewhere and this might help you out

```
//first get the term (I used slug, but  you can aslo use 'name'), see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', 'your custom term slug', 'your custom taxonomy' );
//then get the term_id
$term_id = $term->term_id;
//Use 'tax_input' instead of 'post_category' and provide the term_id:
'tax_input' => array( 'your taxonomy' => $term_id )
```

Hope that helps.