# Add tags to when create post in Wordpress Front End

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tags, custom-fields

I currently work for a site where I need to create posts from Front End.
This is my code to create a custom post from frontend of wordpress site.

```
<?php
   $postTitleError = '';

    if (isset($_POST['submitted']))
     {
      if(trim($_POST['postTitle']) === '')
       {
          $postTitleError = 'Please enter a title.';
          $hasError = true;
       }

    $post_information = array(
                'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['postTitle'] ),
                'post_content' => $_POST['postContent'],
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'post_status' => 'publish'
                        );
    wp_insert_post( $post_information );    
  }
?>
```

And this is my HTML Form:

```
<form action="" id="primaryPostForm" method="POST">
    <!-- Title -->
    <input class="addTitle" type="text" name="postTitle" id="postTitle" class="required" />
    <!-- Description -->
    <input class="addDescription required" name="postContent" id="postContent" />
    <!-- Submit button -->
    <button type="submit"><?php _e('Add Product', 'framework') ?></button>
</form>
```

I shown all my tags on the page but I don't know how to assign them into the post.
Currently i am able to create posts using my code but all i need is to add tags into my post.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the following to your $post_information = array():

'tags_input' => array('tag,tag1,tag2');

So your code should look like:

```
$post_information = array( 
      'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['postTitle'] ),
      'post_content' => $_POST['postContent'],
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'tags_input' => array('tag,tag1,tag2')
);
```

This assumes you have enabled tags in your custom post type.

Reference:

- http://www.templatemonster.com/help/wordpress-how-to-enable-and-output-post-tags-for-custom-post-types.html
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434686/wordpress-wp-insert-post-not-inserting-tags
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267422/update-and-add-tags-post-on-save-post-using-wp-update-post